# How do i label my image classification dataset in an efficient way?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, label, conv-neural-network

I am making an image classification `CNN` for which I made a dataset. I have 4 different kinds of images:

- images with higher contrast
- images with noise
- images with jpeg artefact
- unchanged images.

Now I need to label my images so it can classify the problem on the image and try to repair it but I can't find an efficient way to select like all contrast and add a label.

I have already tried web applications like `labelbox.io` but using that I have to do every image manually and I have too many images so doing that would just cost too much time.

Comment: Duplicate [how to add label to image data set for classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612057/how-to-add-label-to-image-data-set-for-classification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt't provide that information but i will consider that your images' names are correctly formated in order to know in which category they belongs to.

So you can loop throught all of you data, and if they belong to a certain category, save the corresponding label in a list and save that list in a .csv :

```
labels = []

for img in os.listdir(IMG_FOLDER):
    if 'contrast' in img:            #if your image name contain 'contrast'
        labels.append((img, 0))
    elif 'noise' in img:
        labels.append((img, 1))
    elif 'jpeg' in img:
        labels.append((img, 2))
    elif 'unchanged' in img:
        labels.append((img, 3))

labels = pd.DataFrame(labels, columns=['name', 'label'])
labels.to_csv('labels.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: ah yes I should have included that data but yes this is exactly what i needed, thank you