# Extract images in a file and the filename as label

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, machine-learning

I have a question when learning a machine learning question. I have a file named Real World, and inside it, there are 60 files named like clocks,  Bed, Bike. And all of these 60 files contain images in this category. So I want to get all these images into python(maybe as a NumPy array) to analyze and make the file name like "clock" as the label of images in this file.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hi MH563, please post some minimal example of the question, things you tried so far and more detailed information: What is the file type that contains the images of different objects?  Which operations do you want to be able to perform on the images afterwards?

Comment: Thanks. It is like there are 60 categories(filename), and each category contains several images(.jpg). And I want to train a classifier, maybe a CNN,  to distinguish these pics. I need some advice to know how to start to solve this problem.

Comment: Without more details on the file type I can't help you in detail. Maybe this helps: [how to add label to image data set for classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612057/how-to-add-label-to-image-data-set-for-classification/41617388)

Comment: Sorry. Actually, I mean folder, not file. And the dataset I am working on is http://hemanthdv.org/OfficeHome-Dataset/ if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using functions in the inbuilt `os` library.
The below code gives you the images as a list of NumPy arrays, and label names in a list.

```
 import os
dir="/dir"
classes=[clas.name for clas in os.scandir(dir) if clas.is_dir()]

X,y=[],[]
for clas in classes:
    path=os.path.join(dir,clas)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        X.append(plt.imread(os.path.join(path,img)))
        y.append(str(clas))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I got a syntax error that `class.name` is an invalid syntax. Do you know why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, because class is a reserved keyword. Change the name to something else and it works, tested it this time :D
There was also a typo with is_dir, I have edited the answer with the working code.